# QTableWidget auto stretch last field just like QTreeWidget does

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qt4.8

Is there anyway to let QTableWidget's header items stretch to full size just like QTreeWidget does ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [`QTableView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html) documentation:

> By default, the cells in a table do not expand to fill the available space.
>
> You can make the cells fill the available space by stretching the last header section. Access the relevant header using [`horizontalHeader()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader) or `verticalHeader()` and set the header's [`stretchLastSection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop) property.

You should give that a try.

```
 QTableWidget *tw = ...;
 tw->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

The `stretchLastSection` documentation has:

> **Note:** The horizontal headers provided by QTreeView are configured with this property set to true, ensuring that the view does not waste any of the space assigned to it for its header.

So that's how the tree views do it.

Comment: This holds true for `QTableView`, not for `QTableWidget`.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: could you elaborate? QTableWidgets are QTableViews.

Comment: No, the methods you mentioned, like `horizontalHeader` or `verticalHeader` don't belong to `QTableWidget`, they belong to `QTableView`. Plus the method don't work as expected in `QTableView` as well, now. I will be posting a question on this shortly.

Comment: QTableWidget extends QTableView, whatever methods the view has, the widget has.

Comment: Oh, now it seems to be working fine. Looks like I was missing a forward declaration. But it doesn't work any way..

Comment: You can also check `horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection` if you're using Qt Designer